# Clarifying field types in F#

Tags: f#, field

After some practice with F#, I have still some points where I need to clear confusion:

The question is specifically about fields in a type.

This is what I understand and, some must be wrong because the naming wouldn't make sense if I was right:

```
let x -> private read-only field, evaluated once
let mutable x -> private mutable field

val x -> public read-only field.. difference with let?
val mutable x -> public mutable field

member this.x -> private read-only field, evaluated every time
member val -> public mutable field.. difference with val? why no mutable keyword?
```

Can someone tell me what is right / wrong, or some concepts I may have gotten wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can pretty much ignore `val` and `val mutable`. Those two are used with an older syntax for defining classes that is not exactly formally deprecated, but I would almost never use it when writing new normal F# code (there are some rare use cases, but I don't think it's worth worrying about those).

This leaves `let` and `let mutable` vs. `member` and `member val`.

- `let` defines a private field that can only be accessed within the class. The value you assign to it is evaluated once. You can also define functions like `let foo x = x + 1` or `let bar () = printfn "hi"` which have body that's evaluated when the function is called.
- `let mutable` defines a private mutable field. This is initialized by evaluating the right-hand side, but you can later mutate it using `fld <- <new value>`.
- `member this.Foo = (...)` defines a get-only property. The expression `(...)` is evaluated repeatedly whenever the property is accessed. This is a side-effect of how .NET properties work - they have a hidden `get()` method that's called whenever they are accessed, so the body is the body of this method.
- `member val Foo = (...)` is a way of writing a property that is evaluated only once. In earlier versions of F#, this was not available, so you had to implement this functionality quite tediously yourself by definining a local field (to run the code once) and then returning that from a regular property:

  ```
  let foo = (...)
  member x.Foo = foo
  ```

Comment: ok, I think the last one is where there is still some confusion: member this. , I understand it, but should I read 'member val foo' as some kind of 'member mutable this.foo'? I don't understand why there is no 'this' in the val syntax. I get the let vs. member, but not why let / let mutable don't translate to member this. and member mutable this.

Comment: so the syntax 'member val Foo' is still tied to the instance, despite lacking the this?

Comment: @Thomas - Yes, that's correct. I think the main reason for not including `this.` in the syntax is that it is initialized at the beginning when the object is being initialized and so accessing other members via `this.` might have some unexpected consequences. But otherwise, it behaves exactly in the same way as the code you'd have to write yourself (that I posted in the answer)